# How to fix the [err-client] Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property 'firstName' on string 'one'

Tags: botframework

While using the Adaptive Cards I am facing an issue related to textinput and am Unable to submit the details from the card input values.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for the community to help with your issue could you please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question to include what you've tried (code or otherwise).

Comment: Does your submit action have a string as its data property?

Comment: Are you still working on this?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have one button perform both a postBack and an imBack. An adaptive submit action's data property serves the double purpose of providing the value for an imBack or a postBack depending on the data type. If it's a string then the action is an imBack. However, when there are input fields in the Adaptive Card, the submit action tries to automatically combine the card's input with the action's data property in order to send a postBack. If the data property is a string instead of an object, the attempt to create additional properties on the string will throw an error.